# Is a Security Token Service required

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, wif, saml, sts-securitytokenservice

We looked at Identity Server and Starter STS seems large to serve a few encrypted claims. So coming to the question

1. Is a STS **required** or **mandatory** to Federate with ADFS 2.0
2. We opted for Identity Server since ADFS 2.0 does not support other data stores
3. Is there a option to serve claims through mvc controllers or something using Windows Identity Foundation and SAML 2.0 Protocol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tagged this with SAML so I presume that's the protocol (rather than WIF).

I assume your application is ASP.NET?

If you want to **federate** with ADFS, then Yes, you need another flavour of STS.

IdentityServer does not support SAML to applications.

There is a [WIF SAML CTP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/card/archive/2011/05/16/announcing-the-wif-extension-for-saml-2-0-protocol-community-technology-preview.aspx).

If you want a .NET application to speak direct to a STS using SAML, you can use the [.NET OpenSSO Fedlet](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17842_01/doc.1111/e17847/about.htm) (or the OpenAM one).

Comment: We also want to authenticate against LDS, SQL stores. ADFS does support only *attributes* from these store. So we thought an STS(custom) is supposed to do the authentication (are we wrong about this decision)

Comment: No you are correct. You need a custom STS e.g. IdentityServer. But IdentityServer does not support SAML. And then you don't need ADFS?

Comment: We need ADFS For sure. But Now i get from the conversation that STS is also required(Such as StarterSTS, IdentityServer ) Thanks for clearing that up. btw do you know any other projects than IdentityServer for use with ADFS 2.0 (Free and Open Sourced )

Comment: There are a few e.g OpenAM, Shibboleth etc. Refer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML-based_products_and_services. However be aware that the configuration for some of these is not trivial!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I fully understand your question, but here's my take:

1. ADFS *is* an STS. You don't need another one.
2. ADFS supports any data stores, but can only authenticate against AD. You can issue
   claims that are stored in LDAP, SQL or anywhere.
3. WIF doesn't support SAML protocol yet.

Why are you considering WIF/Security Tokens to begin with? (e.g. SSO, federation, both, etc)

Comment: From my understanding WIF does support SAML 2.0.  Our STS is built using WIF and we use SAML tokens for authentication.

Comment: WIF supports SAML2.0 "Tokens" not the protocol.

Comment: @EugenioPace SSO is the objective with long term goal on federation too. We are planning for the near future :)

Comment: As the others have pointed out, you need a custom STS for authenticating users in other stores (e.g. SQL, etc). The options mentioned are viable ones.

Answer (score 1):

For your second question, You can always develop custom STS in .NET and add it with ADFS as Identity Provider. As you have mentioned you need to authenticate against the LDS store you can refer to link such as the one given below which would give you more insights:

http://cloudythoughts.siadis.com/windows-azure/windows-azure-appfabric/creating-a-custom-sts-with-windows-identity-foundation

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbertocci/archive/2008/11/26/an-identity-provider-and-its-sts-writing-a-custom-sts-with-the-october-beta-of-the-geneva-framework.aspx

http://www.rahulsingla.com/blog/2012/05/wif-security-token-service-for-active-directory-lightweight-directory-services